# Hadoop (HDFS) - file versioning

Tags: hadoop, version-control, hdfs

At the given time I have user file system in my application (apache CMIS).
As it's growing bigger, I'm doubting to move to hadoop (HDFS) as we need to run some statistics on it as well.
The problem:
The current file system provides versioning of the files.
When I read about hadoop - HDFS- and file versioning, I found most of the time that I have to write this (versioning) layer myself.
Is there already something available to manage versioning of files in HDFS or do I really have to write it myself (don't want to reinvent the hot water, but don't find a proper solution either).

**Answer**

*For full details: see comments on answer(s) below*

Hadoop (HDFS) doesn't support versioning of files. You can get this functionality when you combine hadoop with (amazon) S3:
Hadoop will use S3 as the filesystem (without chuncks, but recovery will be provided by S3). This solution comes with the versioning of files that S3 provides.
Hadoop will still use YARN for the distributed processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versioning is not possible with HDFS. 
Instead you can use [Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html), which provides [Versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) and is also [compatible](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) with Hadoop.

Comment: "Is also compatible with Hadoop". Isn't it that hadoop can use S3 as a file system? So it's not realy versioning then.

Comment: @VandeperreMaarten By compatible I mean Hadoop can read and write from S3. Hadoop can use S3 as FS by not enforcing its native HDFS features on S3.So it does not affect the versioning capability of S3. S3 provides real versioning, unlike the manually invoked or scheduled HDFS Snapshots

Comment: ok, but I can't use this versioning for my file versions, right? As hadoop is storing files in chuncks... So in S3 I would have versioned chuncks, not versioned files. I will have to look to get some versioning on top of hadoop then.

Comment: Yes, You can use S3 versioning for your file versions. If you plan to use S3 as FS, it provides Versioning. And you need not write any versioning layer in addition to S3's versioning. Also Hadoop's block concept does not come into picture as I have explained in my previous comment, Hadoop does not enforce its native features like Blocks/Chunks when the FileSystem is S3. All the features of Amazon S3 will be preserved, and with Hadoop you can perform all the distributed processing on the data stored in S3.

Comment: thx :) but isn't it overkill to use hadoop then and just use S3? Or would you use both?

Comment: S3 is only for storage. S3 being advantageous in Cost and other features compared to HDFS, it is commonly used as the Filesystem for Hadoop. To Process the data stored in S3, YARN (Hadoop) is used. So, it would be S3 for Storage, YARN (Hadoop) for processing. We need both to get Storage benefits of S3 and Distributed Processing benefits of Hadoop.

Comment: Ok, I got it completely now! :) thanks for the explanations :)
So summarized:
hadoop: the processing engine (i.e. YARN) ; 
S3: the storage without chuncks, but backup and recovery provided by S3 + versioning of files by S3?

Comment: Yea.. exactly. Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

HDFS supports snapshots. I think that's as close as you can get to "versioning" with HDFS.